# Using google maps without API Keys?

Tags: asp.net, api, google-maps, key

I am developing a CMS that will use more than one domain and I have to use only one google map script in my page.

Is there a way to use google maps without API key?

Otherwise, it's not working?

Comment: Why not allow users of your CMS specify their own API keys if they need maps?

Answer (score 15):

The [Google Maps API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/) does not require a key.

Like V2, however, you can only use it for applications which are free and publicly accessible.  If it's for a commercial product, you'll need the [Google Maps API Premier](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/)

Comment: if you try to load a web page with a goolge web map on it in an android web view, you need a valid key it seems. and the key you'd use for you android map view won't work.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Google Maps API FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq) page:

> The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 and the Maps Image APIs previously did not require an API console key. This is still supported for legacy applications to ensure backwards compatibility, but is no longer recommended for new applications.

I'd also point out that [their examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) don't include an API key either:

> ```
> <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
> ```

Like Chris B said in his answer, you do need to have a [Google Maps API Premier](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/?csw=1) key if it is for commercial use. See the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_commercial) on the subject.

Comment: Now it is needed to use api key, <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
Can you update your answer with information about new api keys how it will work if I don't provide it?

Comment: @ПавелИванов here is a workaround that I used for Google Maps without API key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148097/google-maps-api-without-key/38809129#38809129

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with any version of the Google Maps API, as described [here](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/472).  Basically the only thing the map actually does if used without a key is display an alert complaining about it.  If you trap the alert and prevent it from being displayed, the map will function as normal.

Example here:  http://codethink.no-ip.org/mapHacks.html

Answer (score 1):

Fairly confident that in order to use their API you need an API Key.

Perhaps [Google maps premiere](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps_features.html) can adhere to your specific problem?

Comment: In the new V3 API, you no longer need a key.

Comment: ...unless you are trying to load a web map application in the web view of an android app.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add an ApplicationSetting to your Web.Config file like so

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="GoogleMapAPI" value="XXXXXX" />
</appSettings>
```

for each domain?

Then add this to your Page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=<%=ConfigurationManager.ApplicationSettings["GoogleMapAPI"] %>&hl=de"
```

You could rig up something similar using your database or your host headers to manage each key per domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to vary the API key (for V2) in JavaScript, you can write a wrapper that contains the code for starting your map.  The JS code then outputs an API key based upon the host name:

```
if (document.domain=="[HOSTNAME 1]") {

  document.write('[JS TAG to Google Maps API with HOSTNAME 1 Key]')

} else if (document.domain=="[HOSTNAME 2]") {

  document.write('[JS TAG to Google Maps API with HOSTNAME 2 Key]')
```

etc...