# How Android users without their own api key can see a Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, testing, api-key

I'm working on a team trying to make an Android app that uses Google maps. We each registered for our own maps api key (debug, version 1). Pretty much any time an individual is working in Eclipse, we have to repaste in our api key to the xml file or we only get the gray grid.

We have been dealing with this but we need to be able to test it with a user who wouldn't have a map api.

What is the solution to this? I did search but I don't see a solution that I can understand. I'm new to Android so please speak to me like I'm retarded.

The answers some people posted are all for web apps. I don't have a CSS file to edit in Android. Also if you point to a page and there are 4-6 different "solutions" on it, I don't know which you are referring to. Also as I mentioned we are using version 1. We can't switch for reasons unrelated to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: `user who wouldn't have a map api.` Users don't have map API keys. The developers do. Just give your user an apk signed a certificate and using that certificate's API key, and he will be able to install and run the app fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187010/using-google-maps-without-api-keys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615104/how-to-use-google-maps-without-api-key

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/signup

Comment: What do you mean, "give your user an apk signed a certificate"? We can't give users certificates, they have to launch the app and see a map. A user doesn't have the ability to add the api to the xml file...??