# Can I (and how to) use styled google maps without API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am theme developer. For my template I have plugin where user can set options for google map and of course generate this on template page. But not everyone have google maps API key. I don't wanna demand from user his api key.
I have also seen template written by someone else and no one wanted from user his api key. So what should I do now with this?

Another question is what javascript code should I use to generate map? In my form I have following fields:

> Map Height (px): (int)
>
> Google Map Address 1: (eg. Wiejska 8 Warsaw)
>
> Google Map Address 2: (optional)
>
> Google Map Address 3: (optional)
>
> Google Map Address 4: (optional)
>
> Google Map Address 5: (optional)
>
> Zoom Level: (int)
>
> Zoom Map on Mouse Wheel: (YES/NO)
>
> Custom Map Style: (YES/NO)
>
> Color Overlay: (e.g #FFF)
>
> Saturation: (int)
>
> Lightness: (int)

Comment: Without API or without API key?

Comment: Not sure. I need only display map with following settings.

Comment: You will need the API for styled maps. But an API key is optional. It is advised to use one, but you don't *have to*.

Comment: Ok but If I'm going to sell my theme, then all my customers will have the same key. So I think that in my case will be better to don't use.

Comment: You want to sell a map? Are you on meth, Walt? ;) Just kidding. Yes, better you don't use a key in case your theme contains a map. But users should be able to indicate their API key if they have one. Before or after generating the theme. Not sure I fully understand your use case though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least for now you can use Google maps without an API key. See [Using google maps without API Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187010/using-google-maps-without-api-keys) for a discussion on the subject.

As for what your code should look at, take a look at Google's [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/). Play around with them, and if you run into issues feel free to ask more specific questions.

Happy coding!